# Some problems about Python 2.x

Tags: list, typeerror, indices

I have some problems about the dictionary
Here my code:

```
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}


def average (number):
    total = 0.0
    for i in number:
        total = total + number[i]
    return total/ len(number)

def get_average(student):
        return average(student["homework"])*0.1 + average(student["quizzes"])*0.3 + average(student["tests"])*0.6

print get_average(tyler)
```

The error:   `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float`

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have posted an answer below. You may want to read-up on how to format code in a SO question to make it easier to read (although I see Haedrian has done it for you now...) Also, your title gives no indication on what the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `average` function:

```
for i in number:
    total = total + number[i]
```

In this loop, `i` is set to each value in the `number` array, not the index.

Your loop could simply be:

```
for i in number:
    total = total + i
```

Equally, this being python, rather than a `for` loop, you could just use the `sum()` function:

```
def average(number):
    return float(sum(number))/len(number)
```